# Exercise on Hirsch's differential topology

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $\Phi=\{\phi_i , U_i\}_{i\in \Lambda}$ be an atlas on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$. Put $\phi_i(U_i)=V_i\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $X$ be the identification space  obtained from $\bigcup_{i\in \Lambda}V_i\times i$ (disjoint union) when $(x,i)\sim (\phi_j\phi_i^{-1}(x),j)$. Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $M$.

I would like some guidance for the proof. Should I induce quotient topology on $X$? Is it also true that $X$ is *diffeomorphic* to $M$? How does one induce a differentiable structure on $X$?

Comment: $X$ gets the quotient topology, yes. Ideally you'd want to write down $\varphi : \bigsqcup V_i \times i \to M$ defined by $\varphi|_{V_i \times i} = \phi_i^{-1}$. Does $\varphi$ "commute with the equivalence relation"? Use the universal theorem of quotient topology to get a map $\tilde{\varphi} : X \to M$. If $(M, \Phi)$ is a differentiable manifold then $X$ gets a natural differential structure (recall that a differentiable structure = transition functions are $C^1$, or $C^k$, or $C^\infty$)

Comment: @BalarkaSen Do we always "pull back" differential structures?